I use ZooKeeper to acquire a distributed lock. If I obtain the lock but the task takes too long to execute, will the lock be released prematurely?
I use ZooKeeper to acquire a distributed lock. If I obtain the lock but the task takes too long to execute, will the lock be released prematurely?
In ZooKeeper, there's a setting for session timeout. I'm not sure what it is. If the task execution time exceeds this duration, will it result in the lock being released prematurely?
